# Adding a section after a symbol to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

So i have a line i need to read and put into a dictionary, the first number is the key and the 4th number is the amount of words that will be associated with the key.

```
f = open("wordnetSample.txt", "r")
D = {}
for line in f:
    L = line.split()
    D.update({L[0]: L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2]})
```

These are a sample of the lines i am putting into a dictionary

```
09826802 18 n 01 Areopagite 0 002 @ 10326901 n 0000 #m 08181009 n 0000 | a member of  the council of the Areopagus  
09826918 18 n 01 Argive 0 002 @ 09729560 n 0000 + 08804512 n 0101 | a native or inhabitant of the city of Argos
```

This is what i have so far for D

```
{'09826802': ['Areopagite'], '09826918': ['Argive']}
```

And i want this:

```
{'09826802': ['Areopagite', 'a member of  the council of the Areopagus'], '09826918': ['Argive', 'a native or inhabitant of the city of Argos']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing it

```
D = {}
for line in f:
    L = line.split()
    L2 = line.split('|')
    D.update({L[0]: (L[4:4 + 2 * int(L[3]):2][0], L2[1].split('\n')[0])})
```

i added another split wrt `'|'`

Comment: I took out the [0] from the `int(L[3]):2][0]` as some of the lines have more than one word in it, but the rest is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("wordnetSample.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        data, label = line.split(' | ')
        field = data.split()
        d[field[0]] = [field[4], label]
```